# Zebra Printer and French Printing

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

I am trying to use Zebra Printer for printing in French.
The problem which I face is as below.
I want to print in French using Zebra MZ220.

The characters will be dynamic

Zebra's programming manual mentions below

> COUNTRY USA
>
> TEXT 4 0 0 8 COUNTRY IS USA
>
> TEXT 4 0 0 15 #$@[]^‘{|}~

will print

> **COUNTRY IS USA**
>
> **#$@[]^‘{|}~**

When I have to print in French, I have to use the command as below.

> COUNTRY FRANCE
>
> TEXT 4 0 0 28 COUNTRY IS FRANCE
>
> TEXT 4 0 0 35 #$@[]^‘{|}~

which will print as

> **COUNTRY IS FRANCE**
>
> **//corresponding french characters//**

Now, how can I directly send the French characters instead of sending replacement characters?

I have banged my head all around to get an answer with no luck.

Please help.

Comment: Do you only have access to MZ or is this a new application? iMZ printers support Unicode when printing using the ZPL commands to print.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some sort of mapping function to perform the translation. You'd call it with what you want to print and it would return what you need to send to get that output, or tell you if that's not possible.

The details depend on the programming language.

Comment: I do not know the complete translation list.

Also, Printce.NETCF prints any language without issues to the Zebra printer. (it is licensed :()

I wonder how would they do it.

Comment: Try printing a set of characters and see what you get.